# Whats the replacement for WebResponse.AllElements in PowerShell Core 6?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, invoke-webrequest

I have to parse a html file (find div with class xyz and use the inner text).

That would be quit simple by using and filtering the `WebResponse.AllElements` collection.  This member seems to be not available in PowerShell Core 6 (on a Mac).

On this platform, I get an `BasicHtmlWebResponseObject` as the return value of the `Invoke-WebRequest $Url` call which lags tis property.

I don't want to use any C# code or external libraries. What would be an maintainable way to get the same functionality as on the Windows PowerShell environment?

Comment: I found out it is the same in PS Core on Windows. I found this https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2867 I understand a big difference between Invoke-WebRequest in PS-Windows and PS-Core is that the first uses IE as engine. PS-Core obviously doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the link. but I have yet no glue how to het the same functionality. Hm.

Comment: Me neither. If I knew I would share it with you.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Me too. Hopefully we find a solution for our issue.