# Why my PowerShell script not run as expected

Tags: html, css, powershell

I have created a script to crawl the IMDB website. My script take a list of IMDB urls, run and extract the data like movie title, release year, plot summary and export it to a text file in CSV. I wrote the script as below.

```
$listToCrawl =  "imdb_link_list.txt"
$pathOfFile = "K:\MY DOCUMENTS\POWERSHELL\IMDB FILE\"
$fileName = "plot_summary.txt"
New-Item ($pathOfFile + $fileName) -ItemType File
Set-Content ($pathOfFile + $fileName) '"Title","Year","URL","Plot Summary"'

Get-Content ($pathOfFile + $listToCrawl) | ForEach-Object {
 $url = $_
$Result =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url

$movieTitleSelector = "#title-overview-widget > div.vital > div.title_block > div > div.titleBar > div.title_wrapper > h1"
$movieTitleNode = $Result.ParsedHtml.querySelector( $movieTitleSelector)
$movieTitle = $movieTitleNode.innerText

$movieYearSelector = "#titleYear"
$movieYearNode = $Result.ParsedHtml.querySelector($movieYearSelector)
$movieYear = $movieYearNode.innerText

$plotSummarySelector = "#titleStoryLine > div:nth-child(3) > p > span"
$plotSummaryNode = $Result.ParsedHtml.querySelector($plotSummarySelector)
$plotSummary = $plotSummary.innerText
$movieDataEntry = '"' + $movieTitle + '","' + $movieYear + '","' + $url + '","' + $plotSummary + '"'
Add-Content ($pathOfFile + $fileName) $movieDataEntry
}
```

The list of urls to extract from is saved in the "K:\MY DOCUMENTS\POWERSHELL\IMDB FILE\imdb_link_list.txt" file and the content is as below.

```
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0472033/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478087/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0285331/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0453562/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120577/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0416449/
```

I just import and run the script. It does not run as expected. The error is threw.

```
Invalid argument.
At K:\MY DOCUMENTS\POWERSHELL\IMDB_Plot_Summar_ Extract.ps1:20 char:1
+ $plotSummaryNode = $Result.ParsedHtml.querySelector($plotSummarySelec ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

I think the problem is due to the CSS selector I use to select the data but I don't know what's wrong. I think I have followed the CSS selector rule.

```
$plotSummarySelector = "#titleStoryLine > div:nth-child(3) > p > span"
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with the thing.

Comment: can't say anything without seeing the HTML structure, I guess.

Comment: You can do it just your self I have provided the links to the pages above. Just input it in Google Chrome and view source.

Comment: Why are you using this `div:nth-child(3)` ? There is a class of the div you can use!

Comment: Well that is what I get when I choose element > copy selector when I inspect it on Google Chrome. What is your suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion is use the `div`'s `class` instead `:nth-child(3)`

Comment: Could you please write the code?

Answer (score 0):

The `ParsedHtml` property is specific to PowerShell for Windows and [doesn't exist in PowerShell Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661025/htmlwebresponseobject-parsedhtml-replacement-in-powershell-core-6), so if you want to future-proof your code you're better off using something like the [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/).

```bsh
# install the HTML Agility Pack nuget package
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe" -OutFile ".\nuget.exe"; 
.\nuget.exe install "HtmlAgilityPack" -Version "1.11.21";

# import the HTML Agility Pack
Add-Type -Path ".\HtmlAgilityPack.1.11.21\lib\Net40\HtmlAgilityPack.dll";

# get the web page content and load it into a HtmlDocument
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0472033/" -UseBasicParsing;
$html = $response.Content;
$doc = new-object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument;
$doc.LoadHtml($html);
```

then you can extract nodes using XPath syntax - e.g. for the title:

```bsh
# extract the title
$titleHtml = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='title_wrapper']/h1/text()[1]").InnerText;
$titleText = [System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlDecode($titleHtml).Trim();
write-host "'$titleText'"; # '9'
```

I'll leave the rest of the document elements as an exercise for the reader :-).